# Prove a functional series is pointwise and/or uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> Determine whether the following sequence is pointwise and/or uniformly convergent
>
> $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and
>
> $$f_n(x)=   \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       n & x\geq n \\
>       1 & x< n \\
> \end{array} 
> \right. $$

So I have concluded that $f_n(x)\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ so the limit function is $f(x)=1$

How would i know prove or disprove uniform convergence? The way the function is shown with $x\leq n$ etc confuses me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $f(x):=1$
$$||f_n- f||_\infty = n-1$$

so no uniform convergence.

However
$$||f_n- f||_{\infty,[0,R]} = 0 $$

for $n>R$, so uniform convergence on bounded intervals.